# How to sort database using date field?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have question that if I have date as string in one column of table on that date basis I want to sort the table into the database.  How can I perform this operation?

```
create table dateTable (
    _id INTEGER, 
    date varchar2(50), 
    name varchar2(50)
);
```

The DBMS is Oracle, if that matters.

> Q: so will there be multiple formats for date, say "dd-mm-yyyy" or "mm-dd-yyyy" in the date field?

A: Yes, the user can type in any format.

Comment: **WHICH** database system, what version/edition there of?? Can you show us the table definition??

Comment: You might want to clue us in on the format of the date as well. If the date is yyyy-mm-dd you won't need a conversion.

Comment: date is in varchar format as i want it to accept the date in any format

Comment: +1 Conrad, this is the sane way to sort dates stored as strings. Nikki, if you don't constrain a format, you are in for a world of hurt.  Unless the date's accuracy isn't really important.  Ambiguous dates will be wrong often enough.

Comment: Well! i was asking out of curiosity. And i know this thing that's why i was asking is there any way to solve this problem

Comment: The only sane way to store dates is as a DATE; you arrange for the input mechanisms to accept any and all formats, but they **must** check that they can interpret the data entered by the user into a valid DATE value. Similarly with presentation (output); you can display the date values any way you like, using any tools and conventions you like. But the storage in the middle should be a DATE. Or, at a pinch, you can store the information twice: once as the string entered by the user so you can reflect that later, and once as a DATE so you can do actual analysis (such as sorting) on the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more column and insert format of the date value. Use that column in the order by clause by converting the varchar to date using "to_date(date_value,date_format)"

```
create table dateTable (date_id INTEGER, date_value varchar2(50),
date_name varchar2(50),date_format varchar2(50));

insert into dateTable values (1,'20101212121212','date1','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
insert into dateTable values (1,'20101212','date1','YYYYMMDD');
insert into dateTable values (1,'20101213','date3','YYYYMMDD');

select * from dateTable
order by to_date(date_value,date_format) desc
```

Comment: but this format not given by user can the query detect the format by itself

Comment: @Nikki: it is hard to work out the date format reliably automatically.  Consider the string: '01/02/03'.  What is the date?  If you're American, it is 2nd January 2003 (unless it is 1903?); if you're British, it is 1st February 2003 (unless...).  And if I entered '01-02-03' it might be that I want it treated as 3rd February 2001 (two-digit year, month, day; abbreviated ISO 8601 format).

Comment: this format is actually given in query but i am inserting date by the user at runtime of application and at that time i can't specify the format.So, it must detect by itself.

Comment: Try Globalization concept in your application. I wonder is this application is in .Net

Answer (score 3):

Store numbers in numeric data types, strings in character data types and dates in date datatypes. If you do it any other way you are doing in wrong and you will be working against the database, which in turn will **seem** to work against you. (which I believe just happened).

As for your question, you just order by the date column. If the rows come out in the "wrong" order, read the previous paragraph again.

```
select *
  from dateTable 
 order by date;
```

Comment: I agree. Never use a character column to store dates or numbers!

Comment: if i used date as datatype to store date but i want to save it in muti formats of date

Comment: A date isn't stored in a specific format in the database. It has an internal representation. You format it on the way out using TO_CHAR or by relying on current settings for NLS parameters. I recommend using TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 1):

select * from dateTable ORDERBy to_dateto_date(date, 'yyyymmdd');

or 
select * from dateTable ORDERBy to_dateto_date(date);

The syntax for the to_date function is:

```
to_date( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )
```

string1 is the string that will be converted to a date.

format_mask is optional. This is the format that will be used to convert string1 to a date.

nls_language is optional. This is the nls language used to convert string1 to a date.

Comment: there is particular default format of date and if i used different format of date while typing it in string then also your query will work or not?

Comment: You can specify the format that you would like to use.                                                                                                                                         For example:

    to_date('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd')  would return a date value of July 9, 2003.
    to_date('070903', 'MMDDYY')  would return a date value of July 9, 2003.
    to_date('20020315', 'yyyymmdd')  would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002.

Comment: Also, the format specifier is optional, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: oh..in that case, why dont you convert it to date in a specific format so that it is consistent?

Comment: if i have used 2/7/1980 where format is DD/MM/YYYY and 7/2/1980 where format is MM/DD/YYYY then problem occurs

Comment: ideally, you should restrict the user entry in a particular format, otherwise, forget the conversion, we would not know what the user intended!! Either specify the format in which the use should enter the data or provide a calender wherein he can select a data or specify three fields one for date (value range between 01-31), month (value range between 01-12) and year.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a date in varchar format if you allow 'any format'.
Try to add a second column with a computed value with a specified fix format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort the database as you want. You need to have some type format for sorting as it can't sort by all formats.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok! If i have used date datatype then
>   also if i want to accept different
>   date formats then what can i do in
>   that situation

This will depend greatly on the language youre using for the application. Normally you would determine the date format from the users locale as part of your internationalization/localization infrastructure. Meaning that the date format used is specifically tied to the locale of the user (ie. en_US, en_GB, de_DE, etc..). If you want to accept any format from anyone without using a locale or user designated format, then you need to write an algorithm to attempt to guess the format, and i dont think there is going to be any way to make that algorithm full proof.

---

Its just a bad design decision to not use a single date format in the database. If you want to accept multiple formats from user's thats a normal and fine thing to do but you should be handling conversion to the DB format on the application side before inserting or using it to query.

Comment: Ok! If i have used date datatype then also if i want to accept different date formats then what can i do in that situation

Answer (score 0):

HI try this directly in query.. Its working for my application

order by m.created_on desc LIMIT 0,5

Comment: can you please explain your answer

Comment: Take field type as datetime.. and than fire query.. like this  SELECT *
FROM `Table name`
ORDER BY created_on
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: take date piker in your text box. where you are taking datevalue from user. and convert it to datetime format and store it into database.